issue with withColumn/withColumnRenamed in spark
we have two columns with same column names but different cases
+----------+----------+
|clientId$_|clientID$_|
+----------+----------+
|         1|         1|
|         2|         3|
|         3|         4|
+----------+----------+

we are cleaning column names in which we are using withColumn/withColumnRenamed
Expected output dataframe is
+--------+--------+                                                             
|clientId|clientID|
+--------+--------+
|       1|       1|
|       2|       3|
|       3|       4|
+--------+--------+

For getting above dataframe, we are doing below operations
for c in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(c, F.col(c).cast(T.StringType())).withColumnRenamed(c, c.split('$_')[0])

Above operation works perfectly fine in pyspark-shell. But in job its failing with
A column or function parameter with name `clientId_$` cannot be resolved

To debug further, we did check output withColumn operation and It returns
+----------+----------+
|clientID$_|clientID$_|
+----------+----------+
|         1|         1|
|         2|         3|
|         3|         4|
+----------+----------+

We thought its issue of caseSensitive flag. But its also true which is correct. Not sure if its bug from spark.
Same code was working fine when we were using spark 3.0.2. This issue poped up when we migrated to spark 3.4.1
Thanks in advance!!

Its hard to say what is happening without a reproducible example. In general I would advice not changing the object you're looping over. You could try with df = df.select([F.col(c).cast(T.StringType()).alias(c.split('$_')[0]) for c in df.columns]) or perhaps with a rstrip('_$') instead of the split.

Can you please add a reproducible example.

In default spark is configured to ignore case sensitivity. So when there are two columns like "ABC" or "abc" it is the same and you should encounter ambigous error during selection. You can try to set: spark.sql.caseSensitive: True. Otherwise it can be that the error is getting throwed in the second iteration of the loop as spark recognizes two columns with same name (because of case insensivity settings). So it changes both columns in the first iteration and in the second iteration the column is not there anymore.
